# Is there a workaround to use an unknown generic which fulfils certain constraints in c#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method which should instantiate a bunch of generic classes in a loop and yield return them. The problem is, that these generic classes have different generic parameters so I don't know how I can achieve this. Is there a way to tell the compiler "here are some generic classes of some type which fulfill your constraints"?

I have done a little example. The example does not compile. The problem occurs inside the `GetTransmission` function of the `TransmissionPlan` class:

```
public abstract class Transmission<TTargetEntity, TSourceEntity> where TTargetEntity : ClientEntity, new() where TSourceEntity : ClientEntity, new()
{
    public abstract string CommandText { get; }
    public abstract TTargetEntity CreateTarget(IDataRecord dataRecord);
    public abstract TSourceEntity CreateSource(TTargetEntity entity);
}

public class TransmissionPlan<T> where T : TransmissionPlan<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<Transmission> GetTransmissions() //I need something like Transmission<?,?> where ? : ClientEntity, new()
    {
        foreach (var type in typeof(T).GetNestedTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Transmission))) //I need something like Transmission<?,?> where ? : ClientEntity, new()
            {
                yield return (Transmission)Activator.CreateInstance(type); //I need something like Transmission<?,?> where ? : ClientEntity, new()                }
        }
    }
}

public class PersonA : ClientEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonB : ClientEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyTransmissionPlan : TransmissionPlan<MyTransmissionPlan>
{
    public class TransmitPerson: Transmission<PersonA,PersonB>
    {
        public override string CommandText => "SOME_SQL";
        public override PersonA CreateTarget(IDataRecord dataRecord)
        {
            var personA = new PersonA();
            //Populate personA from dataRecord
            return personA;
        }

        public override PersonB CreateSource(PersonA entity)
        {
            var personB = new PersonB();
            //Populate personB from personA
            return personB;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Transmit<TTargetEntity, TSourceEntity>(Transmission<TTargetEntity, TSourceEntity> transmission) where TTargetEntity : ClientEntity, new() where TSourceEntity : ClientEntity, new()
    {
        //Do something with transmission-object...
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var transmission in MyTransmissionPlan.GetTransmissions())
        {
            Transmit(transmission);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this is not really achievable in C#. Maybe there is some kind of workaround... Or do I have to call every transmission from hand like this:

```
Transmit(new MyTransmissionPlan.TransmitPerson());
Transmit(new MyTransmissionPlan.TransmitOtherObject());
Transmit(new MyTransmissionPlan.TransmitOneMoreObject());
```

Comment: When you run your code as is, do you get a runtime or compile-time error?

Comment: If you add a base class `Transmission`, the errors will go, but you've only displaced the issue... You most likely want to review the way it should be done.

Comment: @JimG. This code does not compile. The GetTransmissions() Method is not valid, because Transmisson needs two generic parameters. I would need something like Transmission<?,?> where ? : ClientEntity, new()

Comment: Why do you want to close this question? If you vote to close this question, at least tell me WHY you think it should be closed, so i have a chance to improve it.

Comment: Haven't voted for closing, press close button to see the reason the person has chosen: *Needs details or clarity*

Comment: I didnt know that i can see the reason this way. Thats why i thought one should write them in the comments. Thanks for the Info, but I still don't really know whats unclear to the voter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, what type would `var transmission` be in your `Main`? Even with your `Transmission<?, ?>` scheme, you've lost the actual type information, so you won't know what `TTargetEntity` and `TSourceEntity` are when you call `Program.Transmit`.

What you can do is something like this:

```
public interface ITransmittor
{
    void Transmit<TTargetEntity, TSourceEntity>(Transmission<TTargetEntity, TSourceEntity> transmission) where TTargetEntity : ClientEntity, new() where TSourceEntity : ClientEntity, new();
}

public abstract class Transmission
{
    public abstract void Transmit(ITransmittor transmittor);
}

public abstract class Transmission<TTargetEntity, TSourceEntity> : Transmission
    where TTargetEntity : ClientEntity, new()
    where TSourceEntity : ClientEntity, new()
{
    // ...
    public override void Transmit(ITransmittor transmittor)
    {
        transmittor.Transmit(this);
    }
}

class Program : ITransmittor
{
    public void Transmit<TTargetEntity, TSourceEntity>(Transmission<TTargetEntity, TSourceEntity> transmission) where TTargetEntity : ClientEntity, new() where TSourceEntity : ClientEntity, new()
    {
        //Do something with transmission-object...
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var transmission in MyTransmissionPlan.GetTransmissions())
        {
            transmission.Transmit(new Program());
        }
    }
}
```

That is, have a non-generic base class `Transmission`, which has a `Transmit` method on it. Since generic the `Transmission` subclass knows its own type information, it can pass those on to another object in its `Transmit` override.

This is effectively the visitor pattern.

[See on Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Comment: Thank you, that looks very promising. I will try this pattern as soon as i get back to work